# How to pass query arguments in graphql-tool?

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-tools

I am using [graphql-tool](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tools) to mock up data for testing.

I hope to simulate when I select a user, it opens a detail page and shows the user company info.

**Query**

```
const query = `
  query User($id: ID!) {
    user(id: $id) {
      id
      company
    }
  }
`;
```

**Mock server**

```
import { addMockFunctionsToSchema } from 'graphql-tools';
import casual from 'casual';

const allUserIds = ['u1', 'u2', 'u3'];

const mocks = {
  User: () => ({
    id: casual.random_element(allUserIds),
    name: casual.name,
    company: casual.company_name
  })
};

addMockFunctionsToSchema({ schema, mocks });
```

However, right now, when I query with argument id `'u1'`, it will return a random user id for example `'u2'`, which gives me a little trouble to show it in front end.

I thought I can do something like this below, but turns out I am wrong. `user` is `undefined` in the code below.

```
const mocks = {
  User: (user) => ({
    id: user.id || casual.random_element(allUserIds),
    name: casual.name,
    company: casual.company_name
  })
};
```

Is there a way to pass the query arguments in graphql-tools? Thanks

Comment: You're probably better off using a collection of fake/mock objects or a mock data generator with a consistent seed if you'd like to see your test data persistent throughout testing.

Comment: @ClaireLin thanks, I did try actually. But haven't figured out where I should use `casual.seed(123);`. First, I tried to put on top just after import, it does not have any effect. Then I tried to put in mocks like `const mocks = {
  User: () => {
    casual.seed(0);
    return { id: casual.random_element(allUserIds), ... }
  }
};`, it will give me all users with same info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how consistent you want the test data to be. If all you care about is that the `id` remains consistent with your query argument, here is what you can do:

```
const mocks = {
  Query: () => ({
    user: (root, user) => ({
      id: user.id || casual.random_element(allUserIds),
      name: casual.name,
      company: casual.company_name
    })
  })
};
```

[As mentioned here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/mocking.html#Accessing-arguments-in-mock-resolvers) in the documentation, mock functions are just like GraphQL resolvers. So the parameters of the functions follow the same order of `root, arguments, context` that are available for each field.

Please see the [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/1k8134p9l) here for a live demo.

This guarantees whenever you query user with id `u1`, you always receive a user data object with its `id = "u1"` with randomly generated company and name fields. However, if you want the entire user object to be persistent throughout a test, you'll need to create the mock user data outside mock functions and query and filter out data accordingly.

Comment: Thanks!! I missed that part document. I corrected a little bit since based on your old one `User: () => ({
        id: (root, { id }) => id, ...`. When I try to use `id: (root, something) => id`, `something` will always be empty object, which makes `id` is undefined. When I moved it top like `User: (root, user) => ({
    id: user.id || casual.random_element(allUserIds),` then it works.

Comment: Ah you are right. I got confused with your query `User` and the type `User` with PascalCase. I'd suggest to follow the naming convention and rename the query to be camelCase `user` to reduce confusion.

Comment: @HongboMiao I added a live demo and updated the code snippet here to clarify that `user` is in fact a `query`.

Comment: Oh I did follow name conversion. I think you misunderstood my code in question. My `User` is under root mocks (same level with `Query`) which should be capitalized. It is for all `User` type used in all places GraphQL schema, not just in query. But anyway thanks for the direction!